# "Reachability undeclared" error in xcode when I add "AddThis" to my project.

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, reachability, addthis

I want to use AddThis share library in my project. When I add the "AddThis" folder to my project and build the app I'm getting "Reachability undeclared" and "host undeclared" errors in the SHK.m file in the sharekit library.